# Is it possible to change a NavigationButton to display Image instead of Blue Color?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to set a `NavigationButton` to display an Image, instead of only being a blue-colored button.

Currently, I'm displaying a Horizontal, `Scrollview`, that consists of Images.

Those Images should lead to another view, which would be rendered above the `rootView`.

However, when I wrapped those images around a `NavigationButton`, those images turn out to be only blue, instead of displaying the original image intended.

CategoryRow Component (`ScrollView`)

```
ScrollView(showsHorizontalIndicator: false) {
                HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(categorizeCountry()) { place in
                        NavigationButton(destination: PlaceDetail(place: place)) {
                            Image(place.imageName)
                                .resizable()
                                .clipShape(Rectangle())
                                .frame(width: 225, height: 150)
                                .cornerRadius(8)
                                .padding(.leading, 2)
                                .padding(.trailing, 2)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

ContentView (where the CategoryRow is rendered)

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                FeaturedCard(places: fiveRandomPlaces)

                CategoryRow(label: "Australia")
                CategoryRow(label: "Japan")
                CategoryRow(label: "Singapore")
                CategoryRow(label: "Indonesia")

                ForEach(store.places) { place in
                    PlaceCell(place: place)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Been There"))
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: sortPlaces) {
                Text("Sort")
            })
            .listStyle(.grouped)
        }
    }
```

I expect the Images to work as a button (which it did), but still displaying the original image, instead of being all blue.

Images to the expected result and the actual result are the following:

[image: Expected Result]

[image: Actual Result]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to change the rendering mode

```
Image(place.imageName)
    .renderingMode(.original)
```