# SwiftUI:- Image won't show on the View

Tags: swiftui

I am playing around with SwiftUI and I am stuck on this View. everything is working fine but this little bug is very frustrating.I am trying to display the images as a vertical view and it won't show on the view . I know the Images are loaded but the view is not showing it . Its covered in blue color.

```
import SwiftUI 

struct PlanetHome : View {
var planets : [Planet]
var body : some View {
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView {
            ZStack {
                Color.black .edgesIgnoringSafeArea (.all)
                VStack (alignment: .center)
                {
                    ForEach (self.planets.identified(by: \.imageName))
                    {
                        planet in NavigationLink (destination: PlanetDetail(planets: planet))
                        {
                            PlanetsView (planets: planet)
                            .frame (width: 500, height: 500)
                            .padding (.vertical, 5)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle (Text("Planets"))
    }
}
```

}

I tried to put the NavigationView under the ZStack but it did not work.I have no Idea what I did wrong on the code. No error message on the debugger. just doesn't show the images.

Comment: Your code is missing the most interesting bits ;-) Please include **Planet**, **PlanetDetail** and **PlanetsView**.

Comment: This may be a bug in the beta. I think I've seen it come and go in my project. There's some discussion of it here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/119809, but fix listed doesn't work for me

Comment: I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56541718/is-it-possible-to-change-a-navigationbutton-to-display-image-instead-of-blue-col adding .renderingMode(.original) on Image, which I'm guessing is inside your PlanetsView

Comment: This "feature" made my UIImage all show as solid white blocks. I have been blaming Kingfisher and other libraries, until I found this. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

The `NavigationLink` applies a button style to the objects it holds. `Button` does the same. To remove the blue color, add the `buttonStyle` modifier:

```
NavigationLink(destination: ...) {
    ...
}
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

You can create and apply your own button style as well.

Answer (score -1):

> Its covered in blue color.

You can change blue color to whatever you want with .foregroundColor(.YourColor) or just change **Render as Default** to  **Render as Original Image** at **Assets.xcassets -> Pick Any Image ->  Show the Attribute inspector**

To fix other problem you should include **PlanetsView** because when i put  **Image(systemName: "photo")** instead your view it's shows correctly